# What does an orange folder in Android Studio mean?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Please look at the image and explain what does an orange folder mean?

Comment: It makes reference to folder that containts build classes, apks, resources, etc...

Answer (score 1):

These folder will be generated when you build the project. Also, you should exclude these folders in your git repository if you have any.

Comment: how do I exclude these folders in my git repository?

Comment: Just add these in .gitignore file. You can see some of the folder is already there.